# Does Webdriver BiDi work with Selenium RemoteWebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

currently I'am experimenting with webdriver BiDi. So basic tests that use ChromeDriver or FirefoxDriver work well. But if I use RemoteWebDriver with a Selenium 4.10.0 server running, I get the error "WebDriver instance must support BiDi protocol" if a class from bidi package is called.

I find very few infos via google about it. So question is, did I miss something? If I want to use Selenium Server for remot execution I still need the RemoteWebDriver right?